# Transfer of NFT tokens

Tags: eosio.token, tokens

Transfer of NFT tokens.
I need to send NFT tokens using web JS.

I will be able to send coins using this code.
But I can't find anything like this for sending nft tokens
[image]

Comment: Please clearify on what logic you use for your NFT contract.

Comment: You can also checkout the NFT standards here: https://developers.eos.io/welcome/latest/community-developer-tools/index/#non-fungible-token-nft-standards

Comment: I have the same question, have you find your answer ?

Answer (score 0):

the example you are showing is using the `transfer` action of the fungible token contract `eosio.token`

if you would have in place a non-fungible token contract let's say `eosio.nft` it would prolly have an action called `transfer` as well.

and you would send nft tokens using the `eosio.nft::transfer` action in a similar fashion as the code you are pointing out in your question.

Answer (score 0):

To transfer an NFT on EOS / WAX, you can do it like this:

In the transaction, use the account / name `atomicassets / transfer`

```
data: {
    from: 'me.wam',
    to: 'you.wam',
    asset_ids: [1234567890],
    memo: 'sending you an nft'
}
```

Hope this helps :)